# VBA Formula and Text in a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have some vba code to place the value of a formula and text into a specific cell. I want the code to say Leads:(value of formula). Currently my code runs the formula and places the value in the correct box. I just do not know how to add the text with it. The code I have is written below.

```
ws.Range("$B$1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E,""Lead"")"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) will give you the displayed result while leaving the actual raw value in a numerical form for possible further computation or comparison.

```
with ws
    with .range("B1")    '<~~ no need for absolute $ anchors here
        .formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E,""Lead"")"
        .numberformat = "[=1]L\e\a\d\: 0;L\e\a\d\s\: 0"
    end with
end with
```

Comment: What does that number format do? I tried setting a cell (`"Lead"`) with that, and nothing happens.

Comment: @BruceWayne - There are up to four parts to a number format mask (see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)). The backslashes are escape characters so that a **d** does not try to become a **day**, etc. The **0** is what displays the number.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ws.Range("$B$1").Formula = "=""Leads:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""Lead"")&"")"""
```

so that it ends up like the following when applied:

```
="Leads:(" & COUNTIF(E:E,"Lead")&")"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much :)